# how to let user activate their subscription by letting them click on a link in an email which was sent to them, in php?

Tags: php

I know by using:

```
function checkEmail( $email ){
    return filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
}
```

we can check a valid email, but I want to know if it is fake or real by sending an email to the user with an activation link, which they need to click to get registered.

How do you do this whole process using PHP?

Comment: This is from the CodeIgniter forums: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/75576/

Comment: If you down-voted, please explain why. This is a very useful question for SO users who have never done registration validation based on an email.

Comment: @Matt: Because this site isn't "write a tutorial for me" or "give me the code".

Comment: @Rocket that's a valid reason to down-vote. When I wrote my comment, there were exactly zero comments as to *why* anyone down-voted. +1 for you.

Comment: @Matt: I didn't down-vote, but that's why I assume everyone else did :-P

Answer (score 3):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-implement-email-verification-for-new-members/

Try that step-by-step.

This was result two on google for:

```
php check email subscription link
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering that question.